# Customizing model fields by user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am making a CRM, and I ran into one task: I want to make a “Client” model, with all possible fields, and give an opportunity for users to “enable” only those “Client” fields that he needs.
I have little experience and unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution for this for a long time.
I would be grateful if someone can show me an example of how this is done (or a link to a repository with a similar method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is JSONField, new DBMSs support JSON Fields natively and Django has a native support from 3.0, so you can add the extra fields as attributes in a JSON and save to the a column called `extra` for example you want to add a field  called 'mobile2' so rather than creating the column, so you can add it to the extra column like this

```
obj.extra["mobile2"] = "0xxxxx"
```

this allows you to extend quickly and give different attributes per user.